# SQL inner join doens't return proper answer

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, phpmyadmin

Hello i'm making an external application that needs to access and read data from a webserver running a drupal website.

I want to join two tables and read 1 column from the first table, when something from the other table is true.

the tables are "profile" and "user_roles"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRhFG.png

as you can see when i run `"SELECT * FROM users_roles WHERE rid = 10"` it returns results

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU5GL.png

and when i `"SELECT * FROM profile where uid = 220"` it also returns a result, there a alot of users in these tables i just included a small part to demonstrate the point.

But when i run `"SELECT pid FROM profile INNER JOIN users_roles on profile.pid = users_roles.uid WHERE users_roles.rid = 10"`

It returns nothing, if i change the same statement to users_roles.rid = 5 it returns them correctly.
but with 10 it doesn't.

I need to get all the pid's where the role id is a given number
can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Its better if you use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) instead of table images

Answer (score 4):

I think you have the join statement wrong. You need to join on uid columns the  tables like the following

```
  SELECT pid FROM profile 
  INNER JOIN users_roles on profile.uid = users_roles.uid WHERE users_roles.rid = 10
```